# worker role with azure won't start

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-emulator

I have been working with worker role for a long time. Now, when I try to run the cloud-service in the Azure emulator, I see the following error:

> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
>
> Parameter name: size

Here is a screen shot

[image]

Comment: Actually, I think I've seen this before. Are you trying to publish a particularly deep directory structure? I think this message refers to path length... VS and the filesystem allow paths longer than the emulator can handle.

Comment: please include your ServiceDefinition.csdef file contents